# How do I bind the matched key-value pair to a variable in pattern matching case statement?

Tags: python

Following this format:

```py
some_var = "foo"

match some_var:
    case "foo" as result:
        print(result)
```

I would expect to be able to do the same with a dictionary:

```py
mapping = {
    "a": None,
    "b": "b",
}

match mapping:
    case {"a": value} as pair if value is not None:
        print(f"{pair=}, {value=}")
    case {"b": value} as pair if value is not None: # this is matched
        print(f"{pair=}, {value=}")
    case _:
        print("no match")
```

`value` is identified as the value part, and is matched correctly to select `"b"`, but `pair` gets bound to `mapping` rather than the matched object, which is a bit counterintuitive to me. I would expect `{"a": value} as pair` to be the equivalent of `pair = {"a":value}`

What am I doing wrong?